# powershell string/ array modification

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file with some data. I have read the columns of it using

$read=import-csv C:\file.csv | foreach-object {"{0} {1}" -f $*.ColA,$*.ColB}

There are 100+ rows for this.

This is how $read looks:

```
test2pc K:\\
test3pc L:\\
testapc 
testapc C:\\XYZ
testapc C:\\
testapc C:\\
testapc 
testbpc C:\\
testbpc F:\\
testbpc F:\\ABC
testbpc F:\\DEF
testbpc F:\\GHI
```

I am looking to remove all rows except those which have anything after the "\\", and anything that does not have a "\\".  I also am looking to modify those entries, in the end I would be left with

```
\\testapc\C$\XYZ
\\testbpc\f$\ABC
\\testbpc\F$\DEF
\\testbpc\F$\GHI
```

Any inputs greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Where-Object` with a regexp should do the trick:

```
$read=Import-Csv C:\file.csv | Where-Object { $_.ColB -match '\\\\\w' } | Foreach-Object {"{0} {1}" -f $.ColA,$.ColB}
```

If you have anything other than letter after the '\\'s you might need to extend the search to include numbers, special characters, etc.